# Can't get the item images on my tab bar to show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have tried to code a tab view controller in my AppDelegate and I can either change my background color and have no tab bar at the bottom of the screen, or have no background color and an empty tab bar at the bottom.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
    self.firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [self.firstViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    self.topTracksController = [[TopTracksViewController alloc] init];
    self.settingsViewController = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

That is my code inside my AppDelegate currently, and I have items with images in my storyboard already.

Comment: The code you posted makes no use of a storyboard.

Comment: Read the [Tab Bar Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW1) section of the View Controller Catalog for iOS.